# Copy and paste Greek text from PDF gives strange characters

Tags: pdf

I am using FoxitReader PDF and what to copy a greek word into a txt file. But when I copy for example the word "Παράδειγμα" I get ❆♣❼♥t❤s❤.

How can I fix this? I have done some searches but they only include downloading programs like OCR but they only offer more "famous" languages like Spanish.

Comment: i'm assuming it's because you don't have a font that supports that language.

Comment: Looking at the sample file you put in the comment, it looks like that file was generated using MikTex.  They probably used the [Babel option for Tex](http://www.eelvex.net/latex/greek-in-latex/#toc-babel) - when I copy and paste, things like the upper case pi turn into a P, the lower case alpha an a, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Foxit Reader. I've tried this on Adobe Reader and seens to work.
Tried with lots of fonts. And worked on both Notepad and Notepad++.
No encoding change needed for notepad.

Comment: I try to copy paste from link http://ru6.cti.gr/bouras/dialekseis/6/ec_2013-14_part1.pdf a lesson pdf of mine. Can you try and copy any line you like? To see if it works...

Comment: Now I can't. The problem is really the PDF's enconding, I guess.

Comment: @J0hn — From this link, with Safari Mac, I copy and paste, this gives this : Pardeigma — with an alien head ! :-) Something is rotten in this PDF doc. Although it looks nice.